# Notation of Planes

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to finde the line $L := E_0 \cap E_1$, with

$E_0 = \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle ^\perp$

$E_1 = \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle ^\perp + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

But I am unfamiliar with the notation of $E_0, E_1$. I know the notations which can be found in this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29).

Does anyone know this notation, and can point me into the right direction?

Comment: My guess is that $E_0$ is the plane perpendicular to vector $(1,2,1)$ and passing through origin. $E_1$ is the plane perpendicular to $(-1,1,1)$ and passing through $(1,0,0)$. You are asked to find the line $L$ at the intersection of the two planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition, if $W\subset V$ which $V$ is a proper vector space, then $$W^\perp=\{v\in V\mid \langle v,w\rangle=0, ~\forall w\in W\}$$ Here $\langle v,w\rangle$ means the inner product of two vectors. For example, if $W=\{(0,0,z)\mid z\in\mathbb R\}\in\mathbb R^3$ be our usual $z-$ axes in $\mathbb R^3$, then we can find out that

$$W^\perp=\{(a,b,0)\mid~~a,b\in\mathbb R\}$$

Note that $W^\perp$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Very nice, Babak! +

Comment: @amWhy: :-o ${}$

Comment: Hi, Babak! $\ddot\smile\;!$ I'm not having a good day! :-( I hope yours has gone well?